# Subcribed Oberservable: fire manually possible?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an Oberservable for getting data.

I use a Subscription to call it in an interval in my component.

ngOnInit ()
{

```
this.subscr = interval (10000).pipe (
  startWith (0),
  mergeMap (obs => this.myservice.getData ().pipe (catchError (error =>
  {
    // error
  })))).subscribe (resp =>
  {
    // data
  });
}

ngOnDestroy ()
{
  this.subscr.unsubscribe ();
}
```

I like to have the data refreshed by action (e.g. a button).

```
refreshNow ()
{
  this.myservice.getData ().pipe (catchError (error =>
  {
    // error
  })))).subscribe (resp =>
  {
    // data
  });
}
```

But I do not like to have getData multiple times in the code.
Is there a way I can fire this.subscr manually??

Comment: If my answer helped you can you please mark it as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Subject and combine the both with [merge()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge), something like:

```
private readonly triggerRefresh$$ = new Subject<void>();

// ....

this.subscr = merge(interval(10000), this.triggerRefresh$$)
    .pipe (
        switchMapTo(this.myservice.getData ()
            .pipe(catchError (error => {}))
        )
    ).subscribe (resp => {
        // data
      });


refreshNow () {
   this.triggerRefresh$$.next();
}
```

Comment: May I ask whats the meaning of $ at the end of the variables?

Comment: Is just code conventions. `iAmAnObservable$` `iAmSomeKindOfSubject$$`. When a variable end with `$$` it means it can be used to emit new values. When it end with just one `$` it can just be subscribed.

Answer (score 1):

If i unterstand correctly, you could use a second subject which is merged with the interval:

```js
private triggerSubject = new Subject<number>();

ngOnInit() {
  merge (this.triggerSubject, interval(10000)).pipe(
    // startWith (0), // <---- i don't think this is necessary as you do not use the value anyways..
    mergeMap (obs => this.myservice.getData().pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        // error
      })
    ))).subscribe (resp => {
        // data
    });
}

refreshNow() {
  this.triggerSubject.next(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the other answers, you could end up in a situation where

- you wait 7s
- you click on the refresh button
- it triggers the fetch of your data (in let say 0.5s)
- it'll emit the data just received
- it'll wait for the remaining 2.5s (10s - 7s - 0.5s) and do another request

If instead you'd like to:

- be able to refresh at any time
- wait for the request to be done
- once it's done wait 10s then do a refresh (over and over again) until a manual refresh is triggered (in which case you can start from the first step again)

Then you could do the following:

```
private DELAY_BETWEEN_REFRESH = 10_000;

public refresh$$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

public data$ = refresh$$.pipe(
  startWith(null),
  switchMap(() =>
    this.myservice.getData().pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        // do not forget about error handling as
        // it's important for the stream to end gracefully
        // if you do not want to do anything in particular
        // simply do `return EMPTY`
      }),
      repeatWhen((error$) => error$.pipe(delay(DELAY_BETWEEN_REFRESH)))
    )
  )
);
```

The nice thing about this is that you won't have an unconsistent rate of refresh when you also trigger a manual refresh. Manual refresh will always happen instantly but automatic refresh will only ever happens 10s **after the previous request is done**.